# MOSFET for reverse current protection?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-protection, reverse-polarity

I have a package-integrated charging module connected to my 2-cell battery. When the charger is inactive (disconnected from input voltage), the charger eats power from my battery. I thus want to prevent reverse current from going to the charger when it is inactive. When the charger is active, it puts out ~ 8.8 V and 500 mA max.

I'm playing around with modeling of an n-channel MOSFET and it seems like tying the gate to the source (which in this case would be connected to the charger) would work. It is capable of putting through enough power to the battery when the battery is at 8 V, and according to the model, it drops the amperage to <1 μA when the source voltage drops to 0. Is there any reason I should not implement it this way? I'm just surprised I haven't seen this done in any examples of reverse current protection online.

Here are some screenshots of the model:

When charger is active, and assuming the battery is at 8 V, while the charger is at 8.8 V, the mosfet will let through 1.1 A, which is enough for this application:

[image: charger on mode]

When charger becomes inactive, and voltage drops to 0 (or less than Vd), the MOSFET switches off and current goes to <1 μA

[image]

This solution almost seems too simple. Any reason I shouldn't do this? I could also make this model work with a p-channel MOSFET. Any reason I should pick one over the other for this?

EDIT:
@PStechPaul has pointed out that this is only working because the power is flowing through the diode of the MOSFET, so it is essentially just a diode. I don't want to use a diode because of the power losses involved. The charger is being powered from a second battery (3 cell) that is charged by a solar panel, so wasting power must be minimized.

The usual solution to reverse voltage protection is to use a PMOS MOSFET with the source connected to the load, and a gate to ground like this:

[image]

However, I don't believe I can do this because I have a battery instead of a load here. See edited system below:

[image]

So while this will work to conduct power while the charger is on, the issue arrises when the power to the charger is off, like so:

[image]

In this situation, according to the simulator, I will have a reverse current of 422 mA as follows:

[image]

If you can offer any suggestions to make this system work while minimizing power losses that would be very helpful. I know a simple diode would work here, but I would prefer to avoid those power losses.

EDIT 2:

@mkeith
I've simulated the design you show. At a base level it works with a few caveats:

When charger is off and voltage is absolute 0, the current is indeed stopped:
[image: Charger off with 0V]

However if there is any floating voltage above 1.5 V, there will be a reverse current. (I'm not sure if anything would induce a floating voltage, and I don't know if I should be concerned). Here is an example with 2 V floating, and a reverse current. Perhaps a pull-down resistor would solve this.

[image: floating voltage reverse current]

When the charger is on, it does indeed work. However I again wonder what the difference is between this working, and the first figure I posted with just the n-channel MOSFET. Is this running in with a low Rds, vs the circuit I showed is running like a diode? Or is this also running like a diode (and thus has power losses like a diode)?

[image: proper operation]

Comment: I am not reading this. It is too long. Here is how you do it: 
https://components101.com/articles/design-guide-pmos-mosfet-for-reverse-voltage-polarity-protection

Comment: @mkeith If you read it, you might understand why I can't do this... My load is a battery... so the voltage stays positive on the source even after the drain goes to 0, and current will continue to flow (according to models). Please don't answer questions you don't read.

Comment: You have the gate shorted to source, so the MOSFET will always be OFF. But with the source higher than the drain, the body diode will conduct. You could just use a diode for this.

Comment: @PStechPaul Ah, so it is working because it is just flowing through the mosfet diode then? The reason I didn't want to use a diode is because I am powering the charger from a solar powered battery and I don't want to waste power by running it through a diode. But it appears I am effectively just doing that right now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the article that @mkeith linked. It's very similar to what you have, but the MOSFET is turned on so you just have the RdsON losses.

Comment: @PStechPaul I've read that article even before he sent it. The problem I am facing, or believe to be facing, is that I don't have a load on the source (P1) of the mosfet, I have a battery. When I model this out I get a negative current towards the charger. I'll update my post to further explain this.

Comment: Yes, after further thought, I see the problem. I can think of only some more complex possibilities, like a comparator across the MOSFET that turns it on if Vin > Vout, and off if Vin < Vout.

Comment: @PStechPaul Yes, I've thought about doing something like that before, but then I think Im running into the limits of too small of a Vds. When I model this, it acts the same way as the example I first posed in my original question. I think you've illuminated to me that I'm basically running the mosfet as a diode, but to be honest im not sure, and I'm kind of confused. Are you sure that my first example shows the mosfet being used equivalently to a diode? and thus with power losses like a diode? It was essentially a comparator without the op amps.

Comment: I didn't answer a question I didn't read. I COMMENTED on a question I didn't read. In my opinion, the article I linked to was very close to a workable solution. So I don't think I did you wrong. Initially, I stopped reading your question when I saw that you wanted to connect the source and drain of the mosfet (this is called a "diode connected" mosfet... not suitable for passing substantial current with low drop). However I did go back and read the whole question now and provided an answer with a schematic. Hope it helps.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks for the info. I'm trying to research diode connected MOSFETs, as it seems you are verifying my suspicions that I am just running this mosfet in example 1 as a diode. However when I read online, it says that a diode connected mosfet is when the gate and drain are connected together. does this still apply when gate and source are connected together (as in my example)?

Comment: No. For an enhancement mode mosfet, when the gate and source are connected together, the mosfet will always be off (incapable of turning on). So only the body diode will be operational.

Comment: I mis-spoke when I said "diode connected" earlier.

Comment: My suggestion won't work very well. It works OK when VCHARGE is 0V, but once M1 turns on, it will never turn off unless the battery is dead or the charger is completely disconnected (and even then it may need a pull-down). What you really need is an ideal diode, I guess. Or a presence detect switch for the charger plug.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/power-management/power-switches/ideal-diodes-oring-controllers/overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a $3 comparator ([LT1716](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/LT1716CS5TRPBF?qs=ytflclh7QUXuAtnEwJBbpw%3D%3D)), here is a perfect solution:

[image: Solar Charger Protection]

Comment: I wouldn't, mind, however I think that this is essentially an equivalent circuit to my figure1/ figure 2 circuit, just with a 1k resistor between the gate and source. I think the op amp you're using is just going full on when the charger is on, and full off when the charger is off, with the output controlling the gate. Isn't this just the same as controlling the gate using the power state of the charger as I showed? Another difference is that you appear to be using a PMOS. Does that make a difference?

Comment: The main difference is that you are using a PMOS. Does that make a difference in terms of it functioning as a mosfet with low Rds vs a diode?

In your model, when V1 goes to 0, does the voltage on the gate go to 8V? If so, wouldn't this be an equivalent circuit to just tying the gate to the source V2?

Otherwise, if the voltage on the gate goes to 0 volts, then I think it is equivalent to the last figure I showed where I get a negative current.

Comment: I think this will work but VDD for the comparator is connected directly to the battery. The datasheet said 35 uA Iq. That is pretty low so it may be OK depending on the size of the battery and the expectation for how long it can sit on the shelf or whatever.

Comment: In the end phase of the charge process (<100 mA) this might turn off because the voltage across the MOSFET (12 mohm) is below the possible offset error of the OpAmp (1.6 mV).

Comment: You could use a TLV3701 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slcs137d/slcs137d.pdf (about $1.50) with just 1 uA maximum supply current. And it's easy enough to add hysteresis or offset to avoid shutdown at low charging current. The inputs should have resistors anyway, and a bypass capacitor from Vcc to GND. This device also can work with common mode voltage 5V above Vcc,

Comment: Thank you. This is ultimately what led me to my solution. I combined your answer with @mkeith's to come to a solution by using a comparator with hysteresis to drive his solution.

Answer (score 0):

THIS WON'T WORK BECAUSE IT WON'T TURN OFF UNLESS VCHARGE SOMEHOW DROPS TO A VERY LOW VOLTAGE. LEAVING IT HERE BECAUSE OP IS REFERRING TO IT.

When VCHARGE is 8.8 V, it will turn on NMOS M2 which will turn on PMOS M1, providing a low resistance path from charger to battery.

When VCHARGE is 0 V, M2 will be off, so R1 will pull up the gate of M1, turning it off. The body diode of M1 is oriented in such a way that it will be reverse biased when VCHARGE is 0 and BAT1 is above 0 V.

UNFORTUNATELY, ONCE M1 TURNS ON, IT WILL NEVER TURN OFF.

You have to choose a suitable PMOS for M1 based on how much current you need etc. There may be a few PMOS out there that can't handle Vgs of -8.8 V, so keep an eye on that. Make sure Vgs max is +/- 12 V or so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOcGoR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I simulated this model and added it into my main question edits. As I asked in the edit, Is this working like a diode? what will the power loss be? How is it different than my figure 1 example? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Once turned on it will never turn off. A conducting M1 will keep the gate of M2 at BAT+ level, with or without any charger activity.

Comment: @Jens I guess you are right. OP needs an ideal diode.

Comment: @TroyCados let me know if you want me to delete this answer. Since it won't actually work I need to either delete it or add a big note to it saying it won't work.

Comment: @mkeith. I think your note is sufficient. It is still an insightful answer.